# Is it possible to download the arch wiki docs for offline reading?

Tags: mediawiki

On an arch I could simply run: `pacman -S arch-wiki-docs`. But I would like to read the arch wiki docs from my ubuntu laptop. Is there any package that provides that?

Comment: This is not off-topic!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This package is ArchLinux specific - see https://repology.org/project/arch-wiki-docs/versions .

But you can get the contents from its [PKGBUILD](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/arch-wiki-docs) file. This file has a link to the Git-repository with the documentation.

So you need to run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install git python3-lxml python3-pip python3-cssselect python3-kitchen
sudo pip3 install simplemediawiki

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/lahwaacz/arch-wiki-docs
cd arch-wiki-docs
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 python arch-wiki-docs.py --output-directory ./build_wiki --clean --safe-filenames
```

But it seems that they have some obsolete python coding here. So you may need manual patching.