# Is it possible to install Arch packages on Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, 20.04

I'd like to be able to install one particular package (and keep it updated) from Arch: [arch-wiki-docs](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/arch-wiki-docs/) (also [here](https://github.com/lahwaacz/arch-wiki-docs)).

I know it is not recommended to to this, but it's basically just data so it should not hurt.

Suppose it can't be done, how can I go about to unpack the downloadable `.zst` file on Ubuntu?

Comment: You may want to check https://askubuntu.com/a/1211932/66509 .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/q/161503/11316) virtually everybody seemed to be opposed to the idea of doing it. So I guess the answer is: dont't.

However, to unpack the `.zst` file all you need is to install `zstd`:

```
apt install zstd
```

... and unpack it with `tar -xf file.tar.zst`.

In case of the `arch-wiki-docs` package, the contents will end up in `usr/share/doc/arch-wiki/html` (relative to your current folder, unless you run as root and `cd /`).

Comment: How will you keep the wiki updated?

Comment: @DKBose so far: semi-manually, that is a cron-job which will look for the AUR meta-data and pull the update when it changes. If you find a better way, please create your own answer. I'd love to learn of a more convenient method.